# How did Harry’s watch work at Hogwarts?

Tags: harry-potter

How did Harry's watch work in Hogwarts as magic is supposed to render Muggle inventions like electricity and batteries incapable of normal functioning?

Comment: It was, presumably, a wind-up

Comment: I've closed this as a dupe. If there was any useful info about the specifics of Harry's watch, I'd be adding it to my answer on the other question anyway.